# isomorphic graph : Check whether the following graphs are isomorphic or not. If Isomorphic, then establish the isomorphism between them.

Tags: graph-isomorphism

Check whether the following graphs are isomorphic or not. If Isomorphic, then establish the isomorphism between them.
[image: problem image]

Comment: Push $u_1$ and $u_4$ "inside" the box formed by $u_2, u_3, u_5, u_6$...

Comment: Since both graphs are $3$-regular graphs, any bijection that sends two adjacent vertices to adjacent vertices is an isomorphism.

Comment: can you please provide the full  explaination of this question @AmanuelGetachew

Comment: can you please provide the full explaination of this question @angryavian

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The equivalence class

$$
u_6 \Leftrightarrow v_1, \\
u_5 \Leftrightarrow v_4, \\
u_4 \Leftrightarrow v_6, \\
u_3 \Leftrightarrow v_3, \\
u_2 \Leftrightarrow v_2, \\
u_1 \Leftrightarrow v_5 \\
$$

establishes an isomorphism between the two graphs.

Comment: $u_1$ and $u_6$ are adjacent in the graph on the left, but $v_1$ and $v_6$ are not adjacent in the graph on the right.

Comment: sir , what about adjacency matrix  ?  how to write adjacency matrix after mapping ? can you please  help me with also  @vvg

Comment: For isomorphic graphs, adjacency matrices are identical subject to row/column relabeling as per the node equivalence.

Comment: okay sir . thank you for helping me @vvg GBU